# Next.js 13: How to properly redirect to a dynamic route without showing outdated data?

Tags: next.js

I'm working with Next.js and I'm trying to set up a redirection from one page to another dynamically when a button is clicked. Here's the custom hook I've created for this purpose:

```js
    import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

    export function useDynamicRedirect(statusId: number, itemId: number) {
      const router = useRouter();

      const statusIdRedirectMap = {
        1: `/pathA/${itemId}`,
        2: `/pathB/${itemId}`,
        10: `/pathA/${itemId}`, // Some special case
      };

      const redirectPath = statusIdRedirectMap[statusId as keyof typeof statusIdRedirectMap];

      return () => {
        if (redirectPath) {
          router.replace(redirectPath, {
            scroll: false,
          });

          console.log(`Redirecting to ${redirectPath}`);

          // Temporary solution:
          // window.location.href = redirectPath;
        } else {
          console.warn(`No redirect path defined for statusId ${statusId}`);
        }
      };
    }
```

**Usage of the Hook**

I'm using the hook within a table component to dynamically create rows with a "View" button that redirects based on the item's status and ID:

```js
<Table.Body className="divide-y">
  {data.map((item) => {
    const redirect = useDynamicRedirect(item.Status, item.Id);

    return (
      <Table.Row
        key={item.Id}
        className="bg-white dark:border-gray-700 dark:bg-gray-800"
      >
        <Table.Cell></Table.Cell>
        {Object.entries(item).map(([key, value], index) => (
          <Table.Cell className="w-full truncate p-3" key={index}>
            {key === "Status"
              ? getStatusDetails(value as number)
              : (value as string)}
          </Table.Cell>
        ))}

        <Table.Cell>
          <a
            className="cursor-pointer rounded-2xl bg-blue-500 p-2 font-medium text-white hover:bg-blue-600 dark:text-white"
            onClick={redirect}
          >
            View
          </a>
        </Table.Cell>
      </Table.Row>
    );
  })}
</Table.Body>
```

**Page Rendering the Table**

Here's the component that renders the table. It fetches data and then passes it to a table component:

```js
import { DynamicTable } from "@/components/DynamicTable";
import { publicApiURL } from "@/constants/api";

export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";

export default async function DynamicPage() {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(`${publicApiURL}/Data/List`, {
      cache: "no-store",
    });
    return response.json();
  };

  const items = await fetchData();

  return <DynamicTable items={items} />;
}
```

However, I've run into an issue. When I use this redirection, the data on the page I'm redirected to appears to be outdated.

As a temporary solution, I found that using window.location.href seems to circumvent this problem. I've also tried using `router.replace()` and `router.push()` from next/navigation, exporting this [`dynamic`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config) constant from the page and using cache as `no-store` & `no-cache` in the fetch API without success.

Any insights on why this is happening and how I can resolve it while using Next.js's router?

Comment: Why did you add the router redirect code in the cleanup section of your custom hook?

Comment: @RobinThomas I see where the confusion might come from. The hook is structured to return a function that, when invoked, performs the redirect. This design allows the redirect to only occur when the returned function is explicitly called (like on a button click) rather than every time the component renders.

Comment: Not sure I follow. If you add router redirect in an `onClick` event handler of a button, that redirect will be triggered only on the button (and not every time the button re-rendered)

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. Just to clarify my understanding: if I directly executed the ```router.replace``` logic inside the ```useDynamicRedirect``` hook without wrapping it in a function, it would run during every component render. However, by wrapping it in a function and returning that function, the redirect logic should only be triggered when the button is clicked, correct?

Comment: No, I'm saying you don't even need `useDynamicRedirect`. You just need `onClick` handler within which you add the `router.redirect`.

Comment: Oh, I initially created the useDynamicRedirect hook thinking I might reuse the logic in multiple places, but if it's just for this specific button, your approach seems far cleaner.

Comment: If it's ok, shall I write an answer explaining the same?

Comment: @RobinThomas Absolutely, that would be great!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255017/discussion-between-robin-thomas-and-ari).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, I think its better to simplify your code to avoid the problem altogether.

You have used a custom hook `useDynamicRedirect`, to return a function within which you have a router redirect. This seems to be an overkill for this purpose.

Rather than do that, let's remove this custom hook and use the router redirect within the onClick handler.

```
const onClick = () => {
  const statusIdRedirectMap = {
    1: `/pathA/${item.Id}`,
    2: `/pathB/${item.Id}`,
    10: `/pathA/${item.Id}`, // Some special case
  };

  const statusId = item.Status as keyof typeof statusIdRedirectMap;
  const redirectPath = statusIdRedirectMap[statusId];

  if (redirectPath) {
    console.log(`Redirecting to ${redirectPath}`);

    router.replace(redirectPath, {
      scroll: false,
    });
  } else {
    console.warn(`No redirect path defined for statusId ${statusId}`);
  }
}

return (
  <Table.Cell>
    <a
      className="cursor-pointer rounded-2xl bg-blue-500 p-2 font-medium text-white hover:bg-blue-600 dark:text-white"
      onClick={onClick}
    >
      View
    </a>
  </Table.Cell>
)
```